# AngularJS search in ng-repeat by formatted date without controller

Tags: angularjs, date, search, format, angularjs-ng-repeat

How can I filter result of ng-repeat by date?
In the repeating objects I have a field of type Date. In the view I have a text input to write search query. I use date filter to format a Date. I want to make a textual search.

I found one way how to make such search:

```
<thead>
<tr>
  <td><input ng-model="search.surname"/></td>
  <td><input ng-model="search.name"/></td>
  <td><input ng-model="search.patronymic"/></td>
  <td><input ng-model="search.passport" /></td>
  <td><input ng-model="search.birthdayStr" /></td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="client in clients | filter:search" 
    ng-init="client.birthdayStr = ( client.birthday.value | date:'dd.MM.yyyy' )">
  <td>{{client.surname.value}}</td>
  <td>{{client.name.value}}</td>
  <td>{{client.patronymic.value}}</td>
  <td>{{client.passport.value}}</td>
  <td>{{client.birthdayStr}}</td>
</tr>
```

But it looks terrible. Are there any other ways to do the same without using a controller?

Comment: Your question is how to make it look better, or do you want it to function differently?

Comment: @JonathanRowny, how to make the code look better. I just don't want to use controller for Date formatting.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. In your question you're indicating that you have a problem making your filtering look more elegant, but in the code example you're actually using `ng-init` just to make a temporary date variable that is used only for displaying purposes. While you're at it, why don't you just replace `{{client.birthdayStr}}` with `{{client.birthday.value | date:'dd.MM.yyyy'}}` and get rid of the `ng-init` expression altogether?

Comment: @Stewie, the problem is that I added ng-init to make it work somehow. I'm not very experienced with AngularJS. The fact is that if I remove ng-init and use `{{client.birthday.value | date:'dd.MM.yyyy'}}` the filtering by date field does not work at all. I also tried to write a custom validator, but I always get 0 as an actual parameter.

Comment: I see. Didn't notice that you were using `birthdayStr` in your last input element. Two solutions: 1) Write a custom filter (which seems a bit as overkill here), 2) Prepare the `birthdayStr` inside the controller where you're fetching/creating the `clients` array.

Comment: @Stewie, it's a bit pity. I hoped that I have missed some magic function to make it work without ng-init and all these temp vars/models. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Besides, the [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngInit) do actually say that _"The only appropriate use of ngInit is for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat"_, so your existing solution is, in my opinion, quite valid, although somewhat convoluted to the casual observers.